# How to overwrite method in Mantine React Table without losing previous functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mantine

I am using in my project MantineReactTable and I want to add one more action when visibility of the column is changed. I have read that there's a function for that: onColumnVisibilityChange but I don't know how to overwrite it without losing all previous functionality.

```
const table = useMantineReactTable({
   ...
   onColumnVisibilityChange: () => {
     // here new behaviour on top of the previous functionality
   }
})
```

I read the documentation: [https://www.mantine-react-table.com/docs/api/table-options#onColumnVisibilityChange-prop:~:text=onColumnVisibilityChange](https://www.mantine-react-table.com/docs/api/table-options#onColumnVisibilityChange-prop:%7E:text=onColumnVisibilityChange) but as I understand it's only possible to overwrite it completly which is not what I want.

Comment: Did you read [the docs for that function](https://www.mantine-react-table.com/docs/api/table-options#onColumnVisibilityChange-prop)?  If so, what part do you not understand?  Please update your post with answers to these questions.  Note that there is documentation also on [how to work with the table's internal state](https://www.mantine-react-table.com/docs/guides/state-management).

Comment: I did, and as I wrote I don't understand how to keep the previous behaviour. I know how to overwrite it completly but this is not what I want.

Comment: What about the second document do you not understand?  There are sections on managing individual states, entire states, persisting the state, with a working example that you can inspect and experiment with.

Comment: I am checking it, but looks good so far. Will try it and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the second document, there I found answear for my problem! :)